# Counter in for loop and resetting counter

Tags: python, counter

I have the following code:

```
for i in range(10):
    while True:
       num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
       print("The double of",num,"is",2 * num)
    print('10')
```

What i am want to do is after 10 iterations, message should print 10. It does that but only once, how can i reset the counter so it will start again after it reaches 10?

What i want the program to do is print '10' after 10 iterations but the loop is infinite so it never breaks.

Comment: So basically you want to run the `for i in range(10):` loop again? If so, you can either wrap that loop in another loop, or wrap it in a function and call it after your loop finishes.

Comment: `While True:...` will run forever - When do you want the loop to stop asking for an integer?

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your question to make it clear what you want your code to do. Currently people are writing answers without really knowing how to help you. That's not a great use of people's time.

Comment: Switch the `while` and `for` statements round. Then it will run forever and print '10' after every 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this, you would loop only once and check the counter if it's divisable by 10 to print the message

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    print("The double of",num,"is",2 * num)
    if i%10==0:
        print('10')
```

If you want the infinit loop:

```
i = 1
while True:
    num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    print("The double of",num,"is",2 * num)
    if i%10==0:
        print('10')
    i+=1
```

The result is for `for i in range(1,21)` will be

```
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
10
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
The double of 50 is 100
10
```

Comment: How can i fix this for infinate loop? NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: Maybe something like this? 
`while True:
    counter = 0
    num = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    print("The double of",num,"is",2 * num)
    if counter == 3:
        print('10')
    counter +=1`

Comment: You would need to initialize the counter, I updated the code you can take a look

Comment: Could you check again? It does not even ask for input!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you trying to achieve from this program? I've removed the input statement in the for loop while I was testing the code, I'll go ahead and add it for you :)

Comment: I want an infinite loop but it prints 10 after 10 iterations! This process repeats again!

Comment: Cool, the code I've posted should achieve that. It will ask for a number infinitely and every 10 iterations it will print 10

Comment: Thanks for you help

Comment: Sure no problem  :)